# Displaying names of attached policies to an IAM role using Boto3

Tags: boto3

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out which method to use from the IAM Boto3 documentation. I already have a code that gets all the Local policies using

```
response = client.list_policies(
  Scope='Local',
  OnlyAttached=True
)
```

But the code I need is to display the name of the attached policy to a role. I can't figure out which one from this document - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html

Answer (score 1):

I got it working

```
response = client.list_attached_role_policies(
  RoleName='MyRoleName'
)
```